# Could someone explain line after line this code? And why i have an error: "Specified cast is not valid."?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Could someone explain line after line this code? And why i have an error: "Specified cast is not valid."?

I have this error in line:

```
var costQuery = view.Cast<DataRowView>().Select(drv => drv.Row.Field<decimal>("unit_price"));
```

This is this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Page_Catalog_Checkout : System.Web.UI.Page
{
Decimal cost;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Cart"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
    BindBasket();
}

protected void RemoveProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cart = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
    var removedProducts = Basket.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
      .Where(row => ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("RemovedProducts")).Checked)
      .Select(row => Basket.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()).ToList();
    cart.RemoveAll(removedProducts.Contains);
    BindBasket();
}

protected void BindBasket()
{
    var sql = "SELECT product_id, product_name, unit_price FROM Products WHERE product_id IN ({0})";
    var values = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
    if (values.Count > 0)
    {
        var parms = values.Select((s, i) => "@p" + i.ToString()).ToArray();
        var inclause = string.Join(",", parms);
        BasketData.SelectCommand = string.Format(sql, inclause);
        BasketData.SelectParameters.Clear();
        for (var i = 0; i < parms.Length; i++)
        {
            BasketData.SelectParameters.Add(parms[i].Replace("@", ""), values[i]);
        }

        DataView view = (DataView)BasketData.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

        var costQuery = view.Cast<DataRowView>().Select(drv => drv.Row.Field<decimal>("unit_price"));
        cost = costQuery.Sum();
        Basket.DataSource = view;
        Basket.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Basket_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Literal total = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("TotalPrice");
        total.Text = cost.ToString("c");
    }
}
}
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: What is data type of `unit_price`

Comment: What is the type of the `unit_price` field in your database?  Is it nullable?

Comment: This is string, and I don't know how and where i could convert it to decimal